# Problem with PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

**Question**
While solving a non-linear partial differential equation, i am stuck to a problem
$$z^2(x^2p^2+q^2)=1$$
And let $$F=z^2(x^2p^2+q^2)-1$$
Where $p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$
And $q= \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

**my approach**
From *Charpit method*
$$\frac{dx}{F_p}=\frac{dy}{F_q}=\frac{dz}{pF_p+qF_q}= \frac{-dp}{F_x+pF_z}=\frac{-dq}{F_y+qF_q}$$

> > $$\frac{dx}{2px^2z^2}=\frac{dy}{2qz^2}=\frac{dz}{2p^2x^2z^2+2q^2z^2}=\frac{-dp}{2xp^2z^2+2pz(x^2p^2+q^2)}=\frac{-dq}{2zq(x^2p^2+q^2)}$$

The solution of the pde is given by
$$dz=pdx+qdy$$
**My problem** is, i am unable to seperate the functions for further solution.
Any subtle hints are highly apperciated.

Comment: What is the boundary condition ?

Comment: The boundary conditions are not given

Comment: Note that $dz=pdx+qdy$ doesn't give the solution of the PDE because it is a general property (total derivative) : $$dz(x,y)=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy$$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z^2x^2\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)^2+z^2\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2=1$$

Below, this is not a direct answer to the question, but an hint, too long to be edited in the comments section.

The change of variables :$\quad\begin{cases}
Z=\frac12 z^2\\
X=\frac12 x^2\\
Y=y
\end{cases}\quad$ transforms the PDE into :
$$\left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial X} \right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial Y}\right)^2=1$$
In the littérature one can find examples of solving the Eikonal equation with various boundary conditions :

Example 11, p.21 in http://www.ehu.eus/luis.escauriaza/apuntes_problemas_y_examene/method-of-characteristics.pdf

Example 2.26, p.21 in https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/436.A1.12f/PDE_Meth_Characteristics.pdf

And on Math.StackExchange :
[Finding a complete integral solution for the Eikonal equation $u_x^2+u_y^2=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945244/finding-a-complete-integral-solution-for-the-eikonal-equation-u-x2u-y2-1)

Comment: Can i use any boundry condition provided above for solution?

Comment: You can find analytic solution in some cases of boundary conditions. I doubt in other cases. Look at the extensive littérature about eikonal equation.

Comment: Thankyou for support